# Expression Engine Problem - Javascript error in comments

Tags: javascript, comments, expressionengine

I am having a problem with the comments system on my site.

The comments are displayed with a javascript error message.

This is the error message I get when a user attempts to post a comment:

.(JavaScript must be enabled to view this email address) posted on Fri Oct 09,  2009 at 04:19 PM

Attached below is the snippet of code that refers to the comments and comments form.

{url_or_email_as_author} tripped on *{comment_date format='%D %M %d'},
 {comment_date format='%Y'}  at  {comment_date format='%h:%i %A'}*
                                            {comment}

I do understand that the {url_or_email_as_author} is nested within the main weblog template and it could be causing problems esp for conditional variables. 
**My question is, from the provided code is there any way I could have the commenters name link to the website url that he/she has entered?** If no website url is entered than the commenters name will just be a name without any link. I’ve tried attaching the code above on to a saperate template and then embedding it on to the main blog template, but this didnt work and it ended up skewing the whole layout.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks a million
Josh

Comment: Your question is confusing - it seems like you're trying to debug one problem and ask for help on another, all at once.  Perhaps clarify and maybe post a link to the site in question.

Answer (score 1):

@philfreo is right: your question doesn't match your title.

1) The "(JavaScript ...)" error is caused by the 'Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links?' function which can be turned off in [the weblog preferences](http://expressionengine.com/docs/cp/admin/weblog_administration/weblog_edit_preferences.html). This function obfuscates the email address, requiring JS to render it correctly.

2) Your comment code should be nested inside the comment entry tag: `{exp:comment:entries}`. You've got the correct variable to show the comment author's URL: they just need to enter their URL when they leave a comment.